# Script the execution (pre/post make) of tasks [Gradle + IntelliJ]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I was trying to use variations of this code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea.workspace.iws.withXml { provider ->
    provider.asNode().appendNode('gradleRocks', 'true')
}
```

To essentially add this block to the proj.iws file:

```
  <component name="ExternalProjectsManager">
    <system id="GRADLE">
      <state>
        <task path="$PROJECT_DIR$">
          <activation>
            <before_compile>
              <task name="compileJava" />
            </before_compile>
            <after_compile>
              <task name="processJava" />
            </after_compile>
          </activation>
        </task>
      </state>
    </system>
  </component>
```

I just want to have the right-click "Execute on ..." options pre-set when I open IDEA. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can now easily configure task triggers using the [gradle-idea-ext-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin)

```
idea.project.settings {
  taskTriggers {
    afterSync tasks.getByName("projects"), tasks.getByName("tasks")
  }
}
```

Official documentation:
https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/Change-log-DSL-v0.2#gradle-tasks-triggers-settings